# Grails createCriteria syntax error

Tags: grails, groovy, createcriteria

I am trying to create a list of companies which appear in either of 2 other lists. I can manage to create a list of companies appearing in 1 other list like this :-

```
       List masterList = Companies.createCriteria().list(){
            'in'("companyname", alistofcompanies) 
            and {
                or{
                    eq("type","T1")
                    eq("type","T2")
                }                
             order ("companyname")
            }     
        }
```

But I don't know how to look for companies in either of 2 other lists. I tried this :-

```
    List masterList = Companies.createCriteria().list(){
            or{
               'in'("companyname", alistofcompanies) 
               'in'("companyname", anotherlistofcompanies)
             }
            and {
                or{
                    eq("type","T1")
                    eq("type","T2")
                }                
             order ("companyname")
            }     
      }
```

but it gives me a syntax error.

Any clues how I should structure this?

Comment: Do you have any error? the code seems correct just need to optimize it.

Comment: Oh, this is so frustrating.  It was giving me a syntax error, but after posting my question here, I guess I must have tidied it up for publishing, its working now!  I must have fixed the syntax error without noticing it.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see any syntax issue except you can improve the code and it is working.

```
 List masterList = Companies.createCriteria().list() {
            'in'("companyname", alistofcompanies + anotherlistofcompanies)
            'in'("type", ["T1", "T2"])
             order("companyname")
  }
```

Comment: Very helpful, and I like the way you've combined the two lists.  That is much tidier.

Comment: @Simon Thank you.